# Group of order $p^2$ is commutative with prime $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Please help me on this one:

> Let $p$ be a prime number, show that each group of order $p^2$ is commutative.

If you do not mind at all, could you please **not** give me the elegant explanation, but instead only the dummies' way? I know it must be against your craft skill, but I am self-studying and my knowledge is spotty at the very best. Thank you for your patience.

PS. The text then hints using these lemmas, but if you have simpler explanation, do please give me that one instead. Thanks again.    
Lemma 1: If $G$ finite and $G/Z(G)$ cyclic, $G$ is commutative.  
Lemma 2: [W. Burnside] $G$ is called *primary* if there exists a prime number $p$ such that $G$ is a $p$-group. If $G \neq \{1\},$ then $Z(G) \neq \{1\}.$

Comment: The center group has to be a subgroup. By Lagrange's theorem, there are only three orders a subgroup can have: $1$ (the trivial subgroup), $p$ or $p^2$ (the whole group, the non-proper subgroup).

Comment: Try to use first Lemma 2 and then Lemma 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center $Z(G)$ is non trivial. If $|Z(G)|=p^2$ then it is obvious.

If $|Z(G)| = p$ then $|G/Z(G)| = p$ and so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic because every group of order $p$ with $p$ prime is cyclic. This implies that $G$ is abelian.

Infact Suppose $G/Z(G) = \langle{\overline{g}}\rangle$ and $a, b \in G$.

Thus in $G/Z(G)$ we have$$\overline{a} =\overline{g}^h  $$ $$ \overline{b} =\overline{g}^k$$ for some $h, k \in \mathbb{N}$. So by definition of lateral class there exist $z_1 , z_2 \in Z(G)$ with

$$a = g^h z_1 \ \ \ \ b = g^k z_2$$

Thus $$ab = g^h z_1g^k z_2 = g^hg^k z_1z_2 = g^{h+k}z_2 z_1 = g^kg^h z_2 z_1 = g^k z_2g^h z_1 = ba$$i.e $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I like your analysis, I think I am going to adopt yours. But would you mind showing us (a) how do you go from "If $|Z(G)| = p$ ..." to "... then $|G/Z(G)|$ is cyclic...", the missing links in the second paragraph? And also, (b) how do you conclude that $a = g^h z_1$ and $b = g^h z_2$? I have up-voted your response and thank you very much.

Comment: @A.Magnus: I have edited

Comment: @A.Magnus: is it clear now ?

Comment: Almost there. What are those overbars at $\bar a, \bar b$ and $\bar g$? Are conjugates? Thanks for your patience; slowpoke turtle here! :-)

Comment: @A.Magnus: the overbars mean they are element of the quotient group; so they represents lateral classes, not elements of $G$

Comment: I think I understand up to $\bar a = \bar g ^h$.  Definition of quotient is $G/Z(G) := \{Z(G)a \mid a \in G \},$ after substituting it becomes $\bar a = z_1 a,$ substituting again it becomes $\bar g ^h = z_1a.$ Correct me if I am wrong. Now, how do you go from there to your $a = g^h z_1$? Thanks again and again.

Comment: @A.Magnus: The elements of $Z(G)$ can be on the right because for a normal subgroup a left lateral class is also right, and viceversa. To write $$\overline{a} = \overline{g}^h$$ means that the elements $a$ and $g^h$ are in the same lateral class

Comment: @A.Magnus: Thus by definition of lateral class there exist $z_1 \in Z(G)$such that $a = g^h z_1$

Comment: @A.Magnus: Similarly there exist $z_2 \in Z(G)$, which can be different from $z_1$, with $$b = g^k z_2$$

Answer (score 2):

Theorem :(first sylow theorem) suppose that $G$ is a finite group and $|G|=p^{n}m$ such that $p \nmid m$ then

1.$G$ include a subgroup of order $p^i$ for  $1\leq i \leq n$
 2. Any subgroup $H$ from $G$ from order $p^i$ is normal subgroup of a subgroup from order $p^i$

Answer : if $G$ be not cyclic then for every elemen except $e$  must have order $p$. Let $|\langle{a}\rangle|=p$ then $\langle{a}\rangle \neq G$,then there exist $b \in G$ such that
$$|\langle{b}\rangle|=p \langle{a}\rangle \cap\langle{a}\rangle = \{e\}$$

By theorem $\langle{a}\rangle$ is normal in subgroup of order $p^2$ in fact it is normal in $G$. 
Also $\langle{b}\rangle$ is normal in subgroup of $G$  then we claim that

$$G \cong \langle{a}\rangle \times \langle{b}\rangle$$

So $G$ is commutative

Comment: Sylow's theorems are more commonly used for groups that are **not** $p$-groups.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is nonabelian. Conjugation induces a map from $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ that descends to a map $f:G/Z(G) \to \operatorname{Aut}(G/Z(G))$. Since finite $p$-groups have nontrivial center, $Z(G) = \mathbb{Z}_p$. Hence $f:\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, and so must be trivial. The result follows.